# How to map results of `dask.DataFrame` to csvs

Tags: python, dask

I create a dataframe with `df=dask.DataFrame.read_csv('s3://bucket/*.csv')`. When i execute a `df[df.a.isnull()].compute` operation, i get a set of rows returned that match the filter criteria. I would like to know which files do these returned rows belong in so that i could investigate why such records  have null values. The `DataFrame` has billions of rows and the records with the missing values are in single digits. Is there an efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV files are small then I recommend creating one partition per file

```
df = dd.read_csv('s3://bucket/*.csv', blocksize=None)
```

And then computing the number of null elements per partition:

```
counts = df.a.isnull().map_partitions(sum).compute()
```

You could then find the filenames

```
from s3fs import S3FileSystem
s3 = S3FileSystem()
filenames = s3.glob('s3://bucket/*.csv')
```

And compare the two

```
dict(zip(filenames, counts))
```